# Error: XMLHttpRequest error in Flutter web

Tags: php, sql, flutter

Im trying to connect my aplication to a DB using SQL, and for that Im using the code that you see below

```
class _Login extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController user = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pass = TextEditingController();

  Future login() async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://charlotsxostapp.com/login.php", ""),
        body: {
          "username": user.text,
          "password": pass.text,
        });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

I dont have any problem  If I compile the project with my IOS/Android device, however When Im testing with chrome this Error appeared:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 909:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44
```

I tried to solve the problem adding some lines about CORS in my php file, however this not solve the problem yet.

```
<?php 

    header("Access-Control_Allow_Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8"); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xx");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
```

I dont know how to solve it, any idea?

Comment: You have typo in your header. It's not `Access-Control_Allow_Origin` but `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - notice underscored/dashes

Comment: OU, PERFECT, works perfect ¡ Thankss

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named:
   flutter_tools.stamp
2. Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the
   file   chrome.dart.
3. Find '--disable-extensions'
4. Add '--disable-web-security'

in my system the chrome.dart file is in C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web\chrome.dart

```
  # line no 203
  '--disable-extensions',
  '--disable-web-security',
```